# For loop in Java not working how I expected. Can someone help me out?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a loop in Java that is meant to calculate values for an array and put them in each index.

Here is what I have:

```
for(int i = 15; i <= 30; i += 5){
        double rate = 0.03;
        int index = 0;

        payments[index] = LoanCalculator(initLoan, rate, i*12);

        index++;

    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("%-2.1f%c", 3.0, percent);
    System.out.printf("%13.2f %9.2f %9.2f %9.2f", payments[0], payments[1], payments[2], payments[3]);
    }
```

Here is what it outputs (note: there is other code that prints out the top portion of the output) :

```
Years:        15        20        25        30
__________________________________________________
3.0%       421.60      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

There is obviously a math error in here somewhere which is really bugging me because I passed the exact same parameters earlier and it was returning correct values.

What I am concerned with is that there are no values being placed in the last three indices. Can anyone explain to me what I have done wrong here?

P.S. Here is the LoanCalculator method I am using:

```
public static double LoanCalculator(double loan, double rate, int payments)
{
    double r = rate/12;
    double monPay = (loan * r * Math.pow(1+r, payments))/((Math.pow(1+r, payments))-1);
    return monPay;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code

```
for(int i = 15; i <= 30; i += 5){
    double rate = 0.03;
    int index = 0;
```

within your `for` loop your are re-setting `index` to zero each time

so the effect of

```
index++;
```

is nullified

Move the declaration of index to before your `for` loop

```
double rate = 0.03;
int index = 0;
for(int i = 15; i <= 30; i += 5){
    payments[index++] = LoanCalculator(initLoan, rate, i*12);
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Sorry to make such a long post for such a small error!

Comment: Cool, please consider upvoting and/or accepting this answer

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your `index` to 0 inside the loop. So only the first item is ever assigned.

You probably need:

```
int index = 0;
for (int year = 15; year <= 30; year += 5) {
    payments[index++] = calculateLoan(initLoan, rate, year * 12);
}
```

Or better (in my opinion):

```
for (int i = 0; i < payments.length; i++) {
    int year = i * 15;
    int month = year * 12;
    payments[i] = calcualteLoan(initLoan, rate, month);
}
```

Comment: I agree that the second block of code is much better. But wouldn't I have to start the loop at 1 to avoid having a year/month of 0? As well as making it

Comment: i <= payments.length     as well as payments[i-1]?

Answer (score 0):

You set `index` to 0 in your for-loop. This makes the loop reset the index each time you call it. The way to fix this would be to instantiate index above the loop and increment in the loop.